# MATLAB eigenvalue from scratch

Tags: matlab

I'm not so familiar with MATLAB, i've just recently started using it, and a need help fixing some problems i've encountred.

```
a = input('Skriv inn en verdi for a: ');
b = input('Skriv inn en verdi for b: ');
c = input('skriv inn en verdi for c: ');
d = input('Skriv inn en verdi for d: ');
 A = [a b; c d]

 %Tester om matrisen er rektangulær
 [na, ma] = size(A);
 if na ~= ma
    disp('ERROR'); 
    return
 end

syms lambda
det =((A(1,1)-lambda)*(A(2,2)-lambda))-(A(1,2)*A(2,1))

 %Currently under development
 e1 = (t + sqrt(t^2 - 4*n*d))/2;
 e2 = (t - sqrt(t^2 - 4*n*d))/2;
if A ~= 0
   x1 = [a-e1; b];

end
```

when I enter 1 as the value for a b c and d i  get this

```
Skriv inn en verdi for a: 1
Skriv inn en verdi for b: 1
skriv inn en verdi for c: 1
Skriv inn en verdi for d: 1

A =

 1     1
 1     1


det =

(lambda - 1)^2 - 1
```

I want it to be written out as lambda^2 + 2lambda +- (c) = 0 (i don't know how to set the whole equation as = 0

Comment: Isn't there a `solve` in the symbolic toolbox? I haven't used this toolbox, but It's an assumption. However, you're probably better off writing out the math by hand. It's not hard for a 2x2 matrix!

Comment: So the problem is that you want to print `lambda^2 + 2lambda +- (c) = 0`, or you want to solve it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I know that solving a 2x2 matrix is easy by hand, but this is a problem from my textbook, where I have to manually find a way to find the eigenvalues without using rref() eig() etc..  with matlab

Comment: @ViG I want it to be able to print that instead of (Lambda -1)^2 like if i choose every value to be 1 i would get lambda^2 + 2lambda = 0, but I don't know why it prints it out as (lambda -1)^2 - 1 shouldnt it just print it out as the form i want it in? solving it is something I think I know how to.

Comment: @user8700908 I meant writing out the system of equations by hand rather than relying on the symbolic toolbox. The calculations are pretty simple. That is how you learn! :)

Answer (score 2):

To rewrite `(lambda - 1)^2 - 1` to `lambda^2 + 2lambda +- (c)` you can use `expand`. If you want to be able to work further with `det` in the form of the equation `lambda^2 + 2lambda +- (c) = 0` then you need a double `=`:

```
det = expand(((A(1,1)-lambda)*(A(2,2)-lambda))-(A(1,2)*A(2,1))) == 0
```

When printed there will also be a double `=`. If you need `det` just for printing purpose then you can use:

```
det = expand(((A(1,1)-lambda)*(A(2,2)-lambda))-(A(1,2)*A(2,1)));
disp([char(det), ' = 0'])
```